# Link to kill a connection of connected user PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of 'Active Users' on my page. Is it possible to create a link to immediately disconnect that user temporarily, and then perhaps regrant them access?
I found it online somewhere :D

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
    $_SESSION['username']=$_POST['username'];
}

?>
             <h1>Currently Active Users</h1><br/>
             <?php 
             $d=date('c',time()-1800);
             $q=mysql_query("select username from navigation where time>'$d'");
             if(mysql_affected_rows()>0){
                 print "<ul>";
                 while($users=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
                    print "<li>{$users[0]}</li>";
                 }
                 print "</ul>";
             }
             ?>
```

Comment: How are you detecting they are active? are you using cookie based authentication?

Comment: Show some code to explain how you list theses so called Active Users.

Comment: Even though you might consider them active they will usually only have a short time connection to your webserver (and thus to the db); so disconnecting would be rather difficult. Btw disconnect from what?

Comment: It POSTS the username in my login.php document

Comment: I think I may need a DELETE action in here at somepoint, they are sticking on my "Show Users" page even after logout, damn!

Comment: Your question is saying you want a way to disable a users access for a set amount of time and then re grant their access. Then in the comments you say you have logged out users appearing after they've logged out. Maybe reword your question?

Answer (score 1):

create DB named `kill` with UID (user_id)

```
<?php
include("db.php");
$bans = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM kill WHERE uid = ".$user_id." LIMIT 1");
$ban = mysql_fetch_assoc($bans);
if ($ban)
{
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM kill WHERE id = $ban[id]");
    die("Banned");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is stateless, so there is no such thing as a "Connected user".

There are things you can do to manipulate the session for a specific user - but without knowing how the session management is implemented (assuming that this concept of 'Active Users' has any correlation to PHP sessions). But you've not provided any information about how the "navigation" table is populated.

Also the code you've presented here is not very well written